# Ember Store: Sort, Filter, Find Records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, findby

I load records into my store in the index route:

```
model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        cars: this.store.query('car',{}).then(function(data){

        })
    });
}
```

I then go to my car route to peekAll (no network request) and get all the car records:

```
model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        cars: this.store.peekAll('car').sortBy('name')
    });
}
```

You'll notice I can use 'sortBy' to sort the records based on the field within the local store db.

What I do NOT understand is how to filter or find records from the store?  For example, what if I wanted to do the following:

- Sort all car records by Name, and then filter/find the cars so it will only return cars bought in the year 1998 or later
- Filter records, so I only display cars that are 'Jaguars'
- Return only a maximum of 10 records, even if the store has more than 10+ records.

I've looked into [findBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable.html#method_findBy) and [filterBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable.html#method_filterBy), but the documentation seems a bit lacking with details on how to implement with examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First if you pass `{}` to `.query()` you probably should use `findAll`.

And you can just use `filter`:

```
this.store.peekAll('car')
  .filter(car => car.get('year') >= 1998)
  .sortBy('name')
  .slice(0, 10);
```

`filterBy` is if you want to filter on a specific value. So if you want all `car`s with the `year` `1998`:

```
this.store.peekAll('car')
  .filterBy('year', '1998');
```